# Pass outer anon class ref to a method in an inner anon class

Tags: java, oop, scope, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

How to pass outer anon class ref to a method in an inner anon class in Java?

I have a method that makes async call to a server - `sendCall(some_args, callback)`. The callback is represented by anonymous class (let's name it `OuterAnon`) and contains a method for failure case. Inside this method a message box is created and `sendCall()` is called each time OK button is pressed. So I need to pass `OuterAnon` to the method again.

Here is a code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
private void sendCall(MyData data, OuterAnon<Boolean> callback){/*...*/}

private void myCall(final MyData data) {
        sendCall(data, new OuterAnon<Boolean>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    final OuterAnon<Boolean> callback = this; //how to avoid this?
                    MessageBox.show(throwable.getMessage(), new MessageListener() {
                        public void process(MessageBox.OnClick action) {
                            if (action == MessageBox.OnClick.OK) {
                                sendCall(new MyData("resend?"), callback);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As you noticed, I take a ref for callback here:

```
final OuterAnon<Boolean> callback = this;
```

and use it here:

```
sendCall(new MyData("resend?"), callback);
```

But I want to avoid ref creation and pass callback like:

```
sendCall(new MyData("resend?"), this); //at the moment we point to MessageListener instead of OuterAnon.
```

Is there any way to do it in Java?

Comment: As here the outer class also anonymous so I think there is no way to do this, If the outer class having some name then it can refer with <outerClassName>.this

Comment: @Krushna, trying to access it using `OuterAnon.this` leads to an error: "OuterAnon is not an enclosing class"

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for us to fix since you've only shown incomplete code with classes that aren't supplied, so I don't know if this example is syntactically correct. That being said, a refactoring like this may suit your needs:

```
  private void myCall(final MyData data)
  {
    sendCall(data, new OuterAnon<Boolean>()
    {
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable)
      {
        showErrorMessage(throwable);
      }
    });
  }

  private void showErrorMessage(Throwable throwable)
  {
    MessageBox.show(throwable.getMessage(), new MessageListener()
    {
      public void process(MessageBox.OnClick action)
      {
        if (action == MessageBox.OnClick.OK)
        {
          sendCall(new MyData("resend?"));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void sendCall(MyData data)
  {
    sendCall(data, this);
  }
```

In general, I think it's a usually good idea to abstract code out of anon inner classes and into their own method on the enclosing class.  It's now testable, reusable, and more readable, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you really *need* to specify the `onFailure` inside the inner class the way you showed the code, and if you *need* to use that specific reference for `callback`, and you *need* to code this way...

Let's answer the question: *no*.

In my attempts, I've achieved 3 ways to access the anon-inner-least instance inside the anon-inner-most instance, but I think that none satisfies what you expect.

In that case, the anon-inner-most doesn't have a reference to the anon-inner-least: as you said, the `this` now points to the anon-inner-least.

Also, I tried to search at the [java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), but couldn't find exactly the answer to the question - if someone find the answer there, please contribute.

My try:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public abstract class AnonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ArrayList<Object>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -5986194903357006553L;

            {
                // initialize inner anon class
                add("1");
            }


            // Way 1
            private Object thisReference1 = this;

            // Way 2
            private Object getThisReference2() {
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                // Way 3
                final Object thisReference3 = this;
                new LinkedList<Object>() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 900418265794508265L;

                    {
                        // initialize inner inner anon class
                        add("2");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean equals(Object innerObj) {
                        // achieving the instance
                        System.out.println(thisReference1);
                        System.out.println(getThisReference2());
                        System.out.println(thisReference3);
                        System.out.println(this);

                        System.out.println();

                        // achieving the class
                        System.out.println(thisReference1.getClass());
                        System.out.println(getThisReference2().getClass());
                        System.out.println(thisReference3.getClass());
                        System.out.println(this.getClass());
                        System.out.println(this.getClass().getEnclosingClass());
                        return super.equals(innerObj);
                    }
                }.equals("");
                return super.equals(obj);
            }
        }.equals("");
    }
}
```